# Promo Shopping Cart Price Rule Buy 3 Get 1 Free

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules

I'm using magento 1.7 Community Edition (CE) 
I want to setup this promo rule
If a customer buys 3 t-shirts from the same category (category 8), he/she will get the third one for free

I set the condition like this:

If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
If total quantity  equals or greater than  3  for a subselection of items in cart matching ALL  of these conditions: 
Category  is  8
and then The Action:
Apply: percent of product price discount
Discount amount: 100
Max quantity discount is applied to: 1

Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :
Category  is 8

The problem is that The Action rule will go though every single row in the cart and discount it for 100% for example if I buy 3 different t-shirts (A, B, C from category 8) and a pants (category 9) it will discount the three t-shirt for 100% so I only pay for the pants.  The rule only work if I buy 3 t-shirt of the same sku, it will discount just one of them, but if I buy 3 t-shirt of the same category it will discount all of it for 100%...

My question is how do I set this shopping cart price rule so that it only discount 1 product per category (category 8) not only per sku.

Answer (score 3):

Buy X get Y free using the promo rules never produces the results you want which is why I wrote a module for it a few years ago. Have a look at my [Buy X Get Y Free module](https://github.com/gaiterjones/magento-buy-x-get-y-free), it has a Category X get Y free feature which will do exactly what you want - Buy 3 items from category 8 - add a free item to the cart.

You can see it working [here](http://dev.gaiterjones.com/magento/buy-x-get-y.html) - buy two or more sauces and you get free spaghetti!

Comment: Your extension, while still useful in other cases, forces a specific "gift product", this is not what OP asked for. The question asks for every Nth product from category X to be free, not add a separate "gift product" as there is no way of knowing what the third/free product will be before hand.